# Datetime + String from a Pandas table into a new table. One line of code

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

I'm a beginner at python.
I'm moving specific cells/scalars from one Dataframe to another.
I'm trying to work out why my first block of code didn't work but my expanded code does.
Why does concat give an error?
My Initial Dataframes:

df1_Data

[image: df1_Data]

and df2_Data

[image: df2_Data]

and code

```
date_string=df1_Data.iat[0,2]
date_string.strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S")    
df2_Data.iat[0,0] = pd.concat([date_string,df1_Data.iat[2,2]])
```

Gives this error:

```
cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'datetime.datetime'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Expanded code

```
date_string = df1_Data.iat[0,2]
date_string.strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S")
PersonDate= (df1_Data.iat[2,2],(date_string))
df2_Data.iat[0,0] = PersonDate
```

Gives my target Dataframe:

[image: df2_Data]

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I've edited to make it more straight-forward. Really what I want is a date and a string to be concatenated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is transpose rows for one row DataFrame:

```
df = df1_Data.set_index(df1_Data.columns[0]).iloc[:, 2].T

df.columns = df.columns.str.strip(':')
```

Your code - you need convert values to strings for possible join together:

```
date_string=df1_Data.iat[0,2].strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S")

df2_Data.iat[0,0] = df1_Data.iat[2,2] + ',' + str(date_string)
```

Comment: Also thanks for the idea to transpose. That'll help down the line.